# Streaming .mp4 video using Red5 oflaDemo and video tag

Tags: html, flash, video, jwplayer, red5

The default oflaDemo application in Red5 uses JWplayer to play flv/mp4 videos. The code (as in the index.html file) is :

```
<center>
<b>RTMP</b>
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'hobbit_vp6.mp4',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '848',
    'height': '360'
  });
</script>
<br />
<div>
```

However, [this page in the JW Player website](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/22644/using-the-html5-video-tag/) states that it is possible to use the HTML5 `video` tag instead of flash to stream the videos. But then, from what I know, the `video` tag does not support RTMP streaming. How do I incorporate the `video` tag into the above code in the oflaDemo `index.html` page?

Comment: That is for JW5. And you can't embed over the <video> tag if you are using Red5/RTMP as RTMP is Flash only.